# Pass Formatted Date to Custom Label from VF template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, customlabel

I have a VF email template. I passed parameters to the custom label. One of them is datetime format. However I want to change the formatted date and then pass it as a parameter.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!$Label.BillPay}" >
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Payee}" />
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Payment_Date__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Here I want to format the Payment_Date__c to dd MMM yyyy and then pass it to Bill Pay.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly specify the format for dates when passing them as a value to a text having placeholders in `apex:outputText`.

You only need to define the date format you want as part of the label.

`Formatted Date - {0, date, dd MMM yyyy}`

> ## Date formatting Example
>
> ```
> <apex:page>
>    <apex:outputText value="The unformatted time right now is: {! NOW() }" />
>    <br/>
>    <apex:outputText value="The formatted time right now is:
>          {0,date,yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z}">
>        <apex:param value="{! NOW() }" />
>    </apex:outputText>
> </apex:page>
> ```
>
> The example above renders as,
>
> ```
> The unformatted time right now is: 11/20/2004 3:49 PM
> <br />
> The formatted time right now is: 2004.11.20 AD at 23:49:02 GMT
> ```

An example is also documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm).

So you don't need to make any change to the code, just update add the format in the Custom Label you are using.